# PDFTron WebViewer: Set the Comb flag to a text field that appears multiple times

Tags: typescript, pdftron

I'm loading a PDF document and I need to be sure that each field whose name has a certain pattern gets converted to a COMB field. Happens that a field can be duplicated, meaning that is possible to find another field with the same.

For each field...

```typescript
const fieldChanged = await PDFNet.runWithCleanup(() => combFieldAdjustmentCallBack(pdfField, configuredMaxLen), this.configurationService.webViewerPDFTronKey);
```

combFieldAdjustmentCallBack implementation

```typescript
      const combFieldAdjustmentCallBack = async (pdfField: Core.Annotations.Forms.Field, 
         configuredMaxLen: number) => {
            let fieldChanged: boolean;
            const itr = await pdfDoc.getFieldIterator(pdfField.name);
            for (; await itr.hasNext(); await itr.next()) {

                const docField = await itr.current();

                // if the field has not set the flag comb; set it and mark the field as changed
                const comb = await docField.getFlag(PDFNet.Field.Flag.e_comb);
                if (!comb) {
                    await docField.setFlag(PDFNet.Field.Flag.e_multiline, false);
                    await docField.setFlag(PDFNet.Field.Flag.e_password, false);
                    await docField.setFlag(PDFNet.Field.Flag.e_no_spellcheck, true);
                    await docField.setFlag(PDFNet.Field.Flag.e_no_scroll, true);
                    await docField.setFlag(PDFNet.Field.Flag.e_rich_text, false);

                    await docField.setFlag(PDFNet.Field.Flag.e_comb, true);

                    const comb = await docField.getFlag(PDFNet.Field.Flag.e_comb);

                    //  Always "Field XYZ is a comb field: false"
                    console.log(`Field ${pdfField.name} is a comb field: ${comb}`);

                    fieldChanged = true;
                }

                // Set max length
                const currentMaxLength = await docField.getMaxLen();
                if (configuredMaxLen != currentMaxLength) {
                    await docField.setMaxLen(configuredMaxLen);
                    fieldChanged = true;
                }

                if (fieldChanged) {
                    docField.refreshAppearance();
                }

                return fieldChanged ?? false;
            }
        };
```

This logic works when the field happens only once, but doesn't work when the field repeats across the PDF.  Please, note ***Always "Field XYZ is a comb field: false***

What I'm missing